# How to enforce unique constraint with LINQ to SQL

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql, unique-constraint

I'd like to enforce a unique constraint on two columns with LINQ to SQL. I have got a constraint configured on a SQL table, but is there a way to use it with LINQ to SQL?

Unique constraint is applied to two columns, both of which are foreign keys.

Thank you

**Edit:** I could catch exception, that's if a very specific exception gets thrown. Alternative is to check state of the table before running any updates/inserts. All seems to be like too much work for a very simple task.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my opinion, L2S should not be doing the actual enforcement of this. Your database should be doing it via a unique constraint. Then, when you attempt to do an insert or update via L2S, simple catch the exception (if any) being returned when you call SubmitChanges().

Comment: So enforcing unique constraints through middle tier by catching and handling exception is fine?

Comment: @vikp - You are not really enforcing it in the middle tier. The database is enforcing it. You are simply catching any errors that might occur during an update/insert in the middle tier. This is perfectly fine.