# Entity Framework Db.SaveChanges() not working?

Tags: entity-framework, savechanges

Can u tell me what is the problem?

[image: can u tell me what's the problem]

Comment: what do you mean "is not working"? what is the exception? what EF version are you using? how do you pass the `db` variable to the `Customer` entity and to the click handler in the aspx page?

Comment: can you tell us what the error is ?  My Crystal ball is in for service

Comment: I am not getting an error. it's not save the values

Comment: db variable in the same class like entity db = new entity(); and also aspx page has different db variable. I think its not working because of that

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using two different instances of the `DbContext` (the `db` variable as you named it) then nothing will be saved when you call `SaveChanges` on a context different than the one where your entities are tracked. You need to use the Attach method first.

```
db.customer_images.Attach(item);
db.SaveChanges();
```

However I think in your case you can avoid the attach step if you refactor a bit you code and don't use the DbContext from the entity itself.

Answer (score 1):

***Before going through my answer, you must check, if you are attaching the item as shown in excepted answer or check this code:.***

```cs
if (dbStudentDetails != null && dbStudentDetails.Id != 0)
{
   // update scenario
    item.Id = dbStudentDetails.Id;
    _context.Entry(dbStudentDetails).CurrentValues.SetValues(item);
    _context.Entry(dbStudentDetails).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
else
{
    // create scenario
    _context.StudentDetails.Add(item);
}

await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

***If above solution doesn't work, then check the below answer.***

> Saw a very wired issue, and thought to must answer this. as this can
> be a major issue if you have lots of constraints and indexes in your
> SQL.

db.SaveChanges() wasn't throwing any error, but not working (I have tried Exception or SqlException). This was not working because the Unique constraint was not defined properly while creating the Entity Models.

**How you can Identified the issue:**

- I connected my SQL Server and opened the SQL Profiler.
- Just before the db.SaveChanges(), I cleared all my profiler logs and ran the db.SaveChanges(). It logged the statement. I copied the script from the profiler and ran the script in SQL Server.
- And bingo, I can see the actual error, which is being thrown at SQL Server side.

(images: have some hints, how you can get the execute statement from Profiler and run on sql server)
[image]
[image]

**What you can do For Entity Framework Core:**

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Students>().HasIndex(p => new { p.RollNumber, p.PhoneNumber }).IsUnique(true).IsClustered(false).HasDatabaseName("IX_Students_Numbers");
}
```

**What you can do For Entity Framework 6 and below:**

```cs
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration;

internal partial class StudentsConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Students>
{
    public StudentsConfiguration()
    {
        HasIndex(p => new { p.RollNumber, p.PhoneNumber }).IsUnique(true).IsClustered(false).HasName("IX_Students_Numbers");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to query your entity by Id, eg:

```
entity = this.repo.GetById(item.id);
entity.is_front = false;

if (dbSaveChanges() > 0)
{ 
   ....
}
```