# How can I catch UniqueKey Violation exceptions with EF6 and SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, exception, entity-framework-6, unique-key

One of my tables have a unique key and when I try to insert a duplicate record it throws an exception as expected. But I need to distinguish unique key exceptions from others, so that I can customize the error message for unique key constraint violations.

All the solutions I've found online suggests to cast `ex.InnerException` to `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException` and check the if `Number` property is equal to 2601 or 2627 as follows:

```
try
{
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    var sqlException = ex.InnerException as System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException;

    if (sqlException.Number == 2601 || sqlException.Number == 2627)
    {
        ErrorMessage = "Cannot insert duplicate values.";
    }
    else
    {
        ErrorMessage = "Error while saving data.";
    }
}
```

But the problem is, casting `ex.InnerException` to `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException` causes invalid cast error since `ex.InnerException` is actually type of `System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException`, not `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException`.

What is the problem with the code above? How can I catch Unique Key Constraint violations?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

With EF6 and the `DbContext` API (for SQL Server), I'm currently using this piece of code:

```
try
{
  // Some DB access
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  HandleException(ex);
}

public virtual void HandleException(Exception exception)
{
  if (exception is DbUpdateConcurrencyException concurrencyEx)
  {
    // A custom exception of yours for concurrency issues
    throw new ConcurrencyException();
  }
  else if (exception is DbUpdateException dbUpdateEx)
  {
    if (dbUpdateEx.InnerException != null
            && dbUpdateEx.InnerException.InnerException != null)
    {
      if (dbUpdateEx.InnerException.InnerException is SqlException sqlException)
      {
        switch (sqlException.Number)
        {
          case 2627:  // Unique constraint error
          case 547:   // Constraint check violation
          case 2601:  // Duplicated key row error
                      // Constraint violation exception
            // A custom exception of yours for concurrency issues
            throw new ConcurrencyException();
          default:
            // A custom exception of yours for other DB issues
            throw new DatabaseAccessException(
              dbUpdateEx.Message, dbUpdateEx.InnerException);
        }
      }

      throw new DatabaseAccessException(dbUpdateEx.Message, dbUpdateEx.InnerException);
    }
  }

  // If we're here then no exception has been thrown
  // So add another piece of code below for other exceptions not yet handled...
}
```

As you mentioned `UpdateException`, I'm assuming you're using the `ObjectContext` API, but it should be similar.

Comment: After checking out the code you shared, I can now see that the problem with my code is so obvious. I should write "ex.InnerException.InnerException as SqlException" instead of "ex.InnerException as SqlException".

Comment: Is there a way to detect also on which column violation occurred? There may be multiple unique keys in one table...

Comment: @Learner The only way I can think of would be to parse the error message (which states the name of the constraint / column), but it wouldn't be a very good solution (error messages might be updated in the future, and more important, are translated in multiple languages)

Comment: Yeah, I thought so... Hopefully they won't translate my unique key name :)... I was thinking to try searching the unique key names inside error message. But is true that it might disappear completely with the new versions... Thanks... Maybe I should stick to "check before operation"

Comment: Along the same lines as this answer is this interesting [blog](http://blog.wassupy.com/2012/10/catching-unique-key-constraint.html)

Comment: Doesn't this break the pattern of the ORM, creating a direct dependency to the database? Does this means that every time I use other databases I have to reprogram the Exception handling to recognize the specific codes?

Comment: Instead of all  "if (dbUpdateEx.InnerException != null)  and after that if (dbUpdateEx.InnerException.InnerException is SqlException ...)" could be used "var sqlException = ex.GetBaseException() as SqlException; if (sqlException != null) { .... }" to clear up the code.

Comment: @ken2k This code depends on SQL Server implementation and will not work for other databases. As correctly Daniel Lobo mentioned it breaks ORM idea.

Comment: I'm just wondering how many times someone has moved their apps to a completely different database system? I've been programming 30 years. Never once did we migrate an application to a different database system

Comment: To handle the EF exceptions in a much elegant manner, and when your DBMS is _not_ only SQL Server, then use this library, https://github.com/Giorgi/EntityFramework.Exceptions

Answer (score 33):

In my case, I'm using EF 6 and decorated one of the properties in my model with:

```
[Index(IsUnique = true)]
```

To catch the violation I do the following, using C# 7, this becomes much easier:

```
protected async Task<IActionResult> PostItem(Item item)
{
  _DbContext.Items.Add(item);
  try
  {
    await _DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
  }
  catch (DbUpdateException e)
  when (e.InnerException?.InnerException is SqlException sqlEx && 
    (sqlEx.Number == 2601 || sqlEx.Number == 2627))
  {
    return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status409Conflict);
  }

  return Ok();
}
```

Note, that this will only catch unique index constraint violation.

Answer (score 9):

```
try
{
   // do your insert
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   if (ex.GetBaseException().GetType() == typeof(SqlException))
   {
       Int32 ErrorCode = ((SqlException)ex.InnerException).Number;
       switch(ErrorCode)
       {
          case 2627:  // Unique constraint error
              break;
          case 547:   // Constraint check violation
              break;
          case 2601:  // Duplicated key row error
              break;
          default:
              break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
       // handle normal exception
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the fact that this adds the extra error code and the switch makes the code look cleaner, but I think there's a small error where you cast the `InnerException` to `ErrorCode`. I think you want to call `GetBaseException()` instead of using `InnerException`.

Comment: Also, this swallows all `SqlException` types instead of just the unique key violations. I think your `default` case should probably rethrow.

Answer (score 7):

```
// put this block in your loop
try
{
   // do your insert
}
catch(SqlException ex)
{
   // the exception alone won't tell you why it failed...
   if(ex.Number == 2627) // <-- but this will
   {
      //Violation of primary key. Handle Exception
   }
}
```

EDIT:

You could also just inspect the message component of the exception. Something like this:

```
if (ex.Message.Contains("UniqueConstraint")) // do stuff
```

Comment: Unfortunately, catch(SqlException ex) doesn't catch the Unique Key violation exception and throws this error: An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: Inspecting "UniqueConstraint" in the error message should work, but it doesn't seem to be the best approach.

Answer (score 7):

I thought it might be useful to show some code not only handling the duplicate row exception but also extracting some useful information that could be used for programmatic purposes.  E.g. composing a custom message.

This `Exception` subclass uses regex to extract the db table name, index name, and key values.

```
public class DuplicateKeyRowException : Exception
{
    public string TableName { get; }
    public string IndexName { get; }
    public string KeyValues { get; }

    public DuplicateKeyRowException(SqlException e) : base(e.Message, e)
    {
        if (e.Number != 2601) 
            throw new ArgumentException("SqlException is not a duplicate key row exception", e);

        var regex = @"\ACannot insert duplicate key row in object \'(?<TableName>.+?)\' with unique index \'(?<IndexName>.+?)\'\. The duplicate key value is \((?<KeyValues>.+?)\)";
        var match = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(regex, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.Compiled).Match(e.Message);

        Data["TableName"] = TableName = match?.Groups["TableName"].Value;
        Data["IndexName"] = IndexName = match?.Groups["IndexName"].Value;
        Data["KeyValues"] = KeyValues = match?.Groups["KeyValues"].Value;
    }
}
```

The `DuplicateKeyRowException` class is easy enough to use... just create some error handling code like in previous answers...

```
public void SomeDbWork() {
    // ... code to create/edit/update/delete entities goes here ...
    try { Context.SaveChanges(); }
    catch (DbUpdateException e) { throw HandleDbUpdateException(e); }
}

public Exception HandleDbUpdateException(DbUpdateException e)
{
    // handle specific inner exceptions...
    if (e.InnerException is System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ie)
        return HandleSqlException(ie);

    return e; // or, return the generic error
}

public Exception HandleSqlException(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException e)
{
    // handle specific error codes...
    if (e.Number == 2601) return new DuplicateKeyRowException(e);

    return e; // or, return the generic error
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to catch unique constraint

```
try { 
   // code here 
} 
catch(Exception ex) { 
   //check for Exception type as sql Exception 
   if(ex.GetBaseException().GetType() == typeof(SqlException)) { 
     //Violation of primary key/Unique constraint can be handled here. Also you may //check if Exception Message contains the constraint Name 
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to be very specific while writing the code.

```
     try
     {
         // do your stuff here.
     {
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         if (ex.Message.Contains("UNIQUE KEY"))
         { 
            Master.ShowMessage("Cannot insert duplicate Name.", MasterSite.MessageType.Error);
         }
         else { Master.ShowMessage(ex.Message, MasterSite.MessageType.Error); }
     }
```

I have just updated the above code a bit and its working for me.