# How to catch DbUpdateException Unique exception?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core, exception

I'm inserting a Tag when it already exists into the Tag table, hence it returns the message,

> Message   "Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.Tag' with unique index 'IX_Tag_Name'. The duplicate key value is (Lemon).\r\nThe statement has been terminated."    string

I've tried to catch this Unique exception by checking for the `Number` 2601 but am unable to access the `Number` property.

[image: The Exception]

Apparently this is how you are suppose to catch the exception but `ex.InnerException.InnerException`  is null, so the switch statement never executes.
[How can I catch UniqueKey Violation exceptions with EF6 and SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31515776/how-can-i-catch-uniquekey-violation-exceptions-with-ef6-and-sql-server)

```
catch (DbUpdateException ex)
{
    if (ex.InnerException.InnerException is SqlException sqlException)
    {
        switch (sqlException.Number)
        {
            // If the tag already exists
            case 2601: // Unique Key violation
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how about you just dont try to insert the duplicate tag? 
Apart from that the exception screenshot shows that its the first ```.InnerException``` however in your code you try to get the inner exception of your inner exception :-D

Comment: Are you intentionally looking "two layers in" for `ex.InnerException.InnerException` or had you meant `ex.InnerException`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is checking the inner exception of your inner exception. This is null, and hence your code is failing. Instead do:

```
         catch (DbUpdateException ex)
        {
            if (ex.InnerException is SqlException sqlException)
            {
                switch (sqlException.Number)
                {
                    // If the tag already exists
                    case 2601: // Unique Key violation
                }
            }
        }
```