Exception filters in C#
I'm interested in handling only certain exceptions in my method, so I've went ahead and added the following filter:
catch( Exception ex ) when( ex.InnerException is SqlException {Number: 2601} ) {

// code removed

Unfortunately, it seems like this doesn't always work, so I had to change the previous snippet to something like this:
When I say that it doesn't always work, what I mean is that it's called from several places (e.g. rest web service, windows 32 service) and it doesn't work for all of them.
I did add a breakpoint to the when clause, but it simply didn't stop there. Since I had a catch all exception block in the parent method, I was able to run this check:

To me, it seems like the filter should catch the exception...
catch( Exception ex ) {
     if( ex.InnerException is not SqlException {Number: 2601} ) { // shouldn't need this...
                throw;
            }
        

Does anyone know why the latest works and the 1st doesn't? If I'm not mistaken, option 1 should be the way to go...am I missing something?

You can set a breakpoint on the when. What do you get if you do that, what is the type of ex.InnerException and what is the value of ex.InnerException.Number in the debugger?

So what you are saying is with snippet 1 you get false positives? Meaning your catch block is entered despite the innerException not being a SqlException with Number 2601?

What do you mean by "doesn't always work"? Right now we can;t answer your question without details.

@DavidG that's basically what I was asking. Judging from the second snippet, OP is getting false positives, am I wrong?

Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31515776/how-can-i-catch-uniquekey-violation-exceptions-with-ef6-and-sql-server.

If you set a breakpoint at { // code removed what do you get, for the above questions, and also the full result of ex.Message?

the latest is is not, the first is is. Could that be it?

"what I mean is that it's called from several places (ex.: rest web service, windows 32 service)" maybe this ?

@ivan-petrov Because he is rethrowing the exception in the if statement, and then continuing with the normal exception handling, inverting the logic is correct.

@Charlieface I've put a breakpoint there but it isn't hit. it's clear that the filter is returning false, but I'm not sure on why...

@IvanPetrov the code is from a repository class which handles eventual index duplication errors. The code is used from a rest controller method and from a window 32 hangfire service. When called from the latter, the exception filter is returning false; when called from the controller method, it works as expected.

What happens if you remove the exception filter and then do the breakpoint I said? Or what happens if you step through the code line-by-line until then? Honestly it sounds like something has gone wrong with your debugging environment.

@Charlieface As you can see in the snippet above, I've ended up removing the filter. And yes, it does work when I remove it.
