# How to count tell if data already exist in a sql table using VB.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have a table that looks like this[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2muyC.png) When I use this code it works fine

```
Private Sub CountData()
    Dim con As New SqlConnection
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Try
        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=LVAPP; Initial Catalog=CFLineTracker;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=CFLineAdmin;Password=aaonunit#1"
        con.Open()
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ItemDetails where ItemMasterId = " & IMID & ""
        RD = cmd.ExecuteScalar
        Label5.Text = RD
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error while inserting record on table..." & ex.Message, "Insert Records")
    Finally
        con.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

But when I try to run this code I get an exception

```
 Private Sub CountData()
    Dim con As New SqlConnection
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand  
    con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=LVAPP; Initial Catalog=CFLineTracker;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=CFLineAdmin;Password=aaonunit#1"
    con.Open()
    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ItemDetails where Serial Number = " & SN & ""
    RDSN = cmd.ExecuteScalar
    Label5.Text = RDSN
End Sub
```

The SQL Exception is:

> Additional information: An expression of non-boolean type specified in
>   a context where a condition is expected, near 'Number'.

I'm using SQL SERVER 2008 R2 VB.net 2013

Comment: If your column name has a space, you need to use [Serial Number]

Comment: JamesZ, I think you can add that as an answer. That will probably solve it.

Comment: @JamesZ yes i'm with JamesZ you can add that as an answer.

Comment: Please *don't* use string concatenation to construct SQL statements. Someone may pass eg `1; DROP TABLE ItemDetails;--` instead of a valid serial number. Use parameterized queries

Comment: now I get Incorrect syntax near '=' SQL Server Error

Comment: Hard to tell why the incorrect syntax without seeing the newest query, but either way you really need to switch to a parameterized query: `cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ItemDetails where [Serial Number] = @sn"`, then `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sn", IMID)`, then on to your existing `RD = cmd.ExecuteScalar`.

Comment: @Ed Gibbs Ok the new code : cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ItemDetails where [Serial Number] = @SN"
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sn", SN)
        RDSN = cmd.ExecuteScalar i get this message now"The parameterized query '(@sn nvarchar(4000))SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ItemDetails where [Seri' expects the parameter '@sn', which was not supplied."}

Comment: Good catch - I confused your first code block with the second and used `IMID` instead of `SN`. Is it behaving for you?

Comment: Sorry - our comments crossed. I think the parameter names are case-sensitive and you have uppercase `@SN` in your query and lowercase `@sn` in your `parameters.AddWithValue`. Try making them the same case.

Comment: @EdGibbs no error message but it didn't count it should have counted 1 it it counted 0.

Comment: @ChuckieChiller - I hate to ask, but if you do the query in SSMS with the `Serial Number` in the WHERE clause do you get a count of zero? This is a really basic query and as far as I can tell the syntax is fine.

Comment: @EdGibbs no error message but it didn't count it should have counted 1 it it counted 0. What I do is scan a serial number tag once that I place the scanned text into a variable called SN from there I want to add it to a table this all works but I want to make sure I don't get duplicates in my table so I do the count before I insert in the table.during the test this serial number already exist.

Comment: Hm, hard to tell without seeing more of the code because it may be a case of transaction isolation levels hiding the newly-inserted value, or whatever - and I'm afraid I can't pursue this because I have to get back to work. In general, if you want to avoid duplicates you should (1) add a unique index to `Serial Number`, (2) insert without checking if the value already exists, and (3) catch/handle the exception if there's a duplicate. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24740451/2091410). Note that the error code in the answer is for PK; for unique index use 2601.

Comment: @EdGibbs as you probalycan tellI'm new to SQL pogramming. Thanks for your time the SSMS gives me this Must declare the scalar variable "@SN".

Comment: As you've got your answer already ([field name with space]), just a question: Are "ID=CFLineAdmin;Password=aaonunit#1" the actual user & pwd? :P

Comment: no they are fake and no it still counts to 0 unless I put the actual serial number 'abc123' in just like that where the @SN should be.