# ASP.NET MVC validate query from controller to ajax

Tags: mysql, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Currently I have an insert query to my table and I don't have any idea how I can validate it, if the data is already exists in the table.

So for now I just used try-catch to handle the duplicate entry. I just wondering if I could return some text If value goes to catch then display it to my view as alert or something.

Here is my query from controller:

```
 public ActionResult AddUser(int id, string name, string age)
 {
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString;

        using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr))
        {
            string sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO myTable (id, name, age) VALUES (@id, @name, @age)";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlQuery, con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", age);

            con.Open();

            try {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch (Exception )
            {
                con.Close();
                return this.Json("This Data already exist on table");
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is my script to read my controller query:

```
 function add(id, name, age) {

        var result = confirm("Are you want to add " + name + " to list?");
        if (result == true) {

            $.ajax({
                url: '/Home/AddUser',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    'id': id,
                    'name': name,
                    'age': age,
                },
                success: function (data) {                                                    
                    alert('Data has been successfully added');
                },
                error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(errorThrown);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

So far I can successfully insert it to my table but if there is already exist and it's a duplicate it will do nothing so the user will not have a prompt if they already added it or already exist or not.

Any suggestions or comments. TIA.

Comment: Are you want to check duplicate inputs in server side? You can set up a stored procedure that accepts name parameter and execute it inside the controller action, then check with `if` condition.

Comment: is this .net core

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider creating a constraint in your database table (**unique** constraint on that column(s)). That will prevent any duplicate records to be saved even if it passes your C# code which is talking to the database.

Add a check to see whether the record [exist](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), just before executing the `INSERT` statement. You can write a SQL statement which checks before the insertion step. May be a stored procedure which has this SQL scripts which does this and you may call the stored procedure from your c# method.

There is no point in returning a redirect response if you are calling this from Ajax code. Consider returning a JSON structure which can tell the client side code whether the record was successfully inserted or duplicate found or code crashed.

Here is a quick and **simple** example, where I am calling the `UserExist` method, which checks whether there is a record with the specified name.  If it returns `false`, I continue to execute my code where I will try to insert. If you are using a stored procedure, you can add the record exist check inside that as well.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddUser(int id, string name, string age)
{
    try 
    {
       // your existing code to insert record to db
       // Check record exist
       if(UserExist(name))
       {
          return Json(new { status="failed", message = "Name exist"});
       }
       // name does not exist. Try to call the Insert code now.

       return Json(new { status="success", message = "Successfully saved"});
    }
    catch (SqlException exs)
    {
       // Check exs to see whether this was caused by unique constraint violation
       return Json(new { status="error", message = "User exist"});
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       // to do : log the exception
       return Json(new { status="error", message = "Error in saving"});
    }
}
private bool UserExist(string name)
{
   // to do: check record exist in db 
   // You may use ExecuteScalar method if you use raw ADO.NET
   // to do : return boolean value.
}
```

and in your `success` handler, check the `status` property of the response json and show the user the appropriate message

```
success:function(data)
{
  if(data.status==="success")
  {
      alert("Saved successfully");
  }
  else if(data.status==="failed")
  {
      alert(data.message);
  }
}
```

You can set the `status` property of your JSON object to `failed` when you are trying to insert duplicate record.

You can use [specific exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24740376/best-way-to-catch-sql-unique-constraint-violations-in-c-sharp-during-inserts) for your exception handling part which can catch the exception when the unique key constraint is violated in the database level. Send a message to user in that catch block as well.

Answer (score 0):

The first step you can do is creating a stored procedure which has output parameters to show insertion status, which must be different when duplicate data is found:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE AddUser(in @id int, @name varchar(50), @age int, out @status varchar(20))
AS
BEGIN
    -- check if duplicate exists
    IF (SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM myTable WHERE name = @name))
        BEGIN
           -- duplicate exist, no insertion to table
           SET @status = 'duplicate';
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
           INSERT INTO myTable (id, name, age) VALUES (@id, @name, @age)
           SET @status = 'success';
        END
    END
END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Then, use the stored procedure name inside `MySqlCommand` and use its output parameter to return the status string:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddUser(int id, string name, string age)
{
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString;
    using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr))
    {
        string sqlQuery = "AddUser";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlQuery, con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", age);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@status", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        con.Open();
        try 
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            return Json(new { status = (string)cmd.Parameters["@status"].Value });
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            con.Close();
            return Json(new { status = "error", message = ex.Message });
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            con.Close();
            return Json(new { status = "error", message = e.Message });
        }

    }
}
```

Then you can output messages depending on current status in AJAX callback:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Home/AddUser',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
       'id': id,
       'name': name,
       'age': age,
    },
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.status === "success")
        {
            alert("Data has been successfully added");
        }
        else if (data.status === "duplicate")
        {
            alert("This Data already exist on table");
        }
        else if (data.status === "error")
        {
            alert(data.message);
        }
    }
    error: function (xhr, status, err) {
        // error handling
    }
}
```

If you don't want to check with `SELECT` query like above, consider altering the table by applying [`UNIQUE` constraint](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-unique-constraint/) and check against error code 1062 in `MySqlException`:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD CONSTRAINT UNIQUE (name);
```