# Use async in lock statement

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-core, async-await, thread-synchronization

I using ASP.NET Core Identity, with Jmeter app I send multiple requests to my web application for create user and it created multiple users with same email, although my `RequireUniqueEmail` is `true`

```
services.AddIdentity<User, Role>(identityOptions =>
{
    identityOptions.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
});
```

When I send requesets one by one, everything is okay and give me duplicate email error in this code

```
var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(userToCreate, userPassword);
```

But when I send multiple requests with Jmeter, above code can't handle duplicate email and after finish of Jmeter requests, I open SQL server and I see at least 10 records with same email are created.
I searched for this problem and I get this solution `Using lock`

```
private static readonly object lockObj = new object();
lock(lockObj)
{
    var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(userToCreate, userPassword);
}
```

But it gives me error and says "You can't use await in lock statement", and second problem is ASP.NET Core Identity doesn't have Sync method for create. How can I create sync method of create in ASP.NET Core Identity ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

first of all you cannot use the `lock` statement with the `await` keyword!
and in your case maybe it's better to use `SemaphoreSlim` object,because only one request can enter the critical section (between `WaitAsync` and `Release`) at a time!

```
private static readonly SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1);

// rest of your code

async Task CreateUserAsync(User userToCreate, string userPassword)
{
    await semaphore.WaitAsync();
    try
    {
        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(userToCreate, userPassword);
    }
    finally
    {
        semaphore.Release();
    }
}
```

and if you need a synchronous version, you can also create a wrapper method that encapsulates the asynchronous call and blocks the execution until the operation is completed.

Answer (score 7):

You should enforce this in the database and not with locks or semaphores in the code. Imagine if your application needs to scale to multiple servers for example.

Add a `UNIQUE constraint` on the email column in the database. When inserting a new user it will give you an error, if the email already exists, that you can [handle in your app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24740376/best-way-to-catch-sql-unique-constraint-violations-in-c-sharp-during-inserts).

Comment: Thanks, I make Email required, and I lock the thread with @freeman solution too. Both (Unique constraint and lock the thread)

Comment: I would skip the lock since it is not needed and will slow down the creation of new users. Just handle the error from the database.

Answer (score 1):

Locks are thread-bound, and `await` continuation can run on any thread, so it breaks .NET lock mechanism.

You should also use async methods in asp.net core, so you need to replace `lock` statement, not method.

There is a [nice library](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx#asynclock) `Nito.AsyncEx` that provides async mutex:

```
private static readonly AsyncLock _mutex = new AsyncLock();
public async Task<SomeType> Something(Type1 userToCreate,Type2 userPassword)
{
  // AsyncLock can be locked asynchronously
  using (await _mutex.LockAsync())
  {
    return await _userManager.CreateAsync(userToCreate, userPassword);
  }
}
```